# Determine the Function from the drawn function

Tags: functional-analysis

I  draw a function. Can any body help me what is the equation of the drawn function. I just attach the photo. Please visit the link. I think it is $f(x)=\dfrac{-x^2}{x^2+1}$, but it is not the exact function that I am looking.

[image]

Comment: For what value of $y$ lies the dashed line $y= ? $.

Comment: There is a horizontal Asymptote at y=1 so it exists to y<1

Comment: There is a vertical Asymptote at x=o, the function is even function, they are symmetric at y axis.

Comment: Then clearly your guess is wrong, because at $x=0$, $f(x) = y = 0$.  Hence, with your suggested function, $(0, 0)$ ought to be intersected by the graph of the function.

Comment: Sorry, the suggested function would be -(x²+1)/x²

Comment: In my suggested function, there is a horizontal function at y=-1 but I need to have y=1

Answer (score 0):

Is it

$$y=\frac{2x^2-1}{x^2}$$

If one square in your picture is half a unit, then subtract one from this to get

$$y=\frac{2x^2-1}{x^2}-1 = \frac{x^2-1}{x^2}$$

And if you want it more "tight" put a scaling $r>0$ in it:

$$\frac{(rx)^2-1}{(rx)^2}$$

Comment: f(x)=x²-1/x² yes it is the function